# Meta Box not being added in plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, php, metabox, oop

I am attempting to create a simple oop plugin that registers a few custom post types and then adds meta boxes to that custom post type.

It is currently adding the post type but it's not adding the metabox with it. I have a class for the meta boxes.

Here is my code.

```
include('class-tracks-meta.php');

// Register activation/deactivation hooks
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Tracks_Plugin', 'set_up' ) );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array('Tracks_Plugin', 'tear_down') );
add_action( 'init', array( 'Tracks_Plugin', 'set_up' ) );


/**
 * Class: Tracks_PLugin
 *
 * Class which holds all of the core functions for instantiating the plugin when it's first enabled before
 * starting to add new songs and genres
 *
 * Changes or patches added to README.md
 */

    Class Tracks_Plugin {

        /**
        * Constructor Setup
        */

        public function __construct() {

            new Tracks_MetaBox();

        }

        /*
        * Call the methods needed to set up the plugin in the WP backend 
        */

        public static function set_up() {
            // static:: used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance, as self:: will call the original method definition
            // Explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this
            // static:: refers to class, $this refers to current object

            static::register_post_type();
            static::register_taxonomies();
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }

        public static function tear_down() {

            flush_rewrite_rules();

        }

        public static function register_post_type() {

            $labels = array(
                'name' => 'songs',
                'singular_name' => 'song',
                'menu_name' => 'Songs',
                'add_new'   => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Song',
                'new_item' => 'New Song',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Song',
                'view_item' => 'View Songs',
                'all_items' => 'All Songs'
            );

            $args = array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'description' => 'Songs Custom Post Type',
                'public'    => true,
                'show_in_menu'  => true,
                'menu_position' => '6',
                'supports'  => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
            );

            register_post_type( 'songs', $args );
}
```

Then my other class for the meta box is this.

```
class Tracks_MetaBox
 {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_metabox' ) );
        add_action( 'save_meta_box_data', array( $this, 'save' ) );
    }

    public function add_metabox() {

         /****************************************************
        Add the meta boxes needed for the Songs CPT
        ****************************************************/

        function tracks_song_name() {
            add_meta_box( 'mb_song_name', 'Song Name', array($this, 'html_song_name'), 'songs', 'normal', 'high' );
        }

        /**
         * Prints the box content.
         * 
         * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
         */

        function html_song_name( $post ) {

            // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later
            wp_nonce_field( 'tracks_save_meta_box_data', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );

            /*
             * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
             * from the database and use the value for the form.
             */
            $tracks_song_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_song_name' );

            echo '<input type="text" id="tracks_song_name" name="tracks_song_name" value="' . esc_attr( $tracks_song_name[0] ) . '" size="25" />';
        }

    }
```

Those are snippets of the two classes as the other code doesn't have any relevance to the question. Then in my main file I create an instance of the main class.

```
/ Initialise our Tracks class
new Tracks_Plugin();
```

Can anyone see why my meta box isn't being created?

Comment: do you register the post type on `init`?

Comment: yes, the post type registers on init and works fine

Comment: Your `Tracks_MetaBox` class looks strange. The `add_metabox` function doesn't do anything and your other functions are declared inside it. Nothing calls `tracks_song_name`, though even if you did, I don't think it would work with them nested like that.